# How to split a string and set the data for each button click action in android?

Tags: android

I am working on android. I have a string that contains '|' and '@' symbol.

```
str = |13651@This is testing1@4769@This is testing2@0@0@4769@1@0@|13652@This is again testing1@4766@This is again testing2@1@1@3245@0@2@|.................

First, I need to split the string upto '|' operator. So i will get data like 

str[0] = 13651@This is testing1@4769@This is testing2@0@0@4769@1@0@

str[1] = 13652@This is again testing1@4766@This is again testing2@1@1@3245@0@2@
```

For the first time i need to set str[0] data. Then when next button is clicked str[1] data has to be set. If again next button is clicked the the str[3] has to be set and so on.

How can I do that? Any help will be thankful.

Comment: can u specify more clearly what u need ,the eg: is not understandable.

Comment: I mean, my string contains | operator and @ operator along with the data. So what i need to do is i need to split the string with | operator first and then need to set the data. For every click action i need to set the data splitted with | operator

Comment: ok split using the below method by thomas88wp and i think u need to maintain a array with pop and push for replacing each portion of string as u need str[1] to replace str[0]. rearranging array can do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking how to split a string, just use the split() method. Here's a [tutorial](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/string-split-example-in-java-tutorial.html).

If I understand the second half of your question correctly, you just have to add an OnClickListener to your button, and change your text to the next section. See the documentation for [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html).

```
private String[] parts;
private int index = 0;

public void onCreate(...) {
    parts = originalString.split("\\|"); //Escape the | with the \\
    showingText = parts[0];
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             if (index < parts.length - 1) {
                 index++;
                 showingText = parts[index];
             }
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Can you please tell me how to set the data dynamically i.e by using a loop..

Comment: Do you mean switch out parts[0] for parts[1] on the first click, then parts[1] for parts[2] on the next click and so on?

Comment: no first part[0] need to be set, then when button is clicked part[1] need to be set and so on...Here i am showing my string statically...but my string contains part[2],parts[3],parts[4] and so on........

Comment: Ok, updated my code to allow it to go on until you're out of parts.

Comment: hi thanks for the example..please can u tell me how to split parts[index] with "@" and then assign it to showingText? I mean i need to split parts[0] and set all those in showtext. Again when next button is clicked set parts[1] to showtext. Here showtext means i want to set the values to textview. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: You would split it with ``String[] atParts = parts[index].split("@")``. That gives you an array, and you can assign the parts to whichever TextViews you need. If you have a TextView, use the setText() method to change its text. If you're not following, you may want to do some [Android tutorials](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) before you try the problem you're working on right now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to split.
Example, you want to split with "|", similar with "@"

```
    String str = "Hello|World";
    String[]token = str.split("\\|");
    // Result : token[0] = ""Hello", token[1] = "World"
```

Comment: You need to use str.split("\\|") because java uses regex to split, and '|' is a reserved character.